# Nested Switch statements

Tags: c++, nested, switch-statement, sudoku

Currently I am trying to create a program which will automatically generate a completed Sudoku board from scratch although the same functions could with minor alteration be used to solve a partially filled Sudoku board. Any way the issue is that when loading a new number into the board you obviously have to check whether the number already exists in the same column or row, but also in the same 3x3 square that it is being loaded into. Using nested switch statements for the part of the program where you must check the number against the numbers in the same 3x3 square and despite that the break statements all appear to be in the correct place. The compliler is saying of the first number of the second case statement that is part of the nested switch statement that : "Error: case label value has already appeared in this switch" even though the number hasn't and the question is why?

Here is the code:

```
bool SudokuClass::checkPresentGrid(int &temporary, int row, int column)
{
bool indicator;
 switch (row)
{
case 0 || 3 || 6:       //If the number is being loaded into row 0,3 or 6
    switch (column)
    {
    case 0 || 3 || 6:   //Check all other spaces in the same 3x3 grid   
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row + 1][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column + 2] || completeSudoku[row + 2][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row + 2][column + 2]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    case 1 || 4 || 7:
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row + 1][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row + 2][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row + 2][column + 1]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    case 2 || 5 || 8:
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row + 1][column - 2] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row + 2][column - 2] || completeSudoku[row + 2][column - 1]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
case 1 || 4 || 7:               //If the number is being loaded into row 1, 4 or 7
    switch (column)
    {
    case 0 || 3 || 6:   //Check all other spaces in the same 3x3 grid   
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row - 1][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column + 2] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column + 2]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    case 1 || 4 || 7:
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row - 1][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column + 1]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    case 2 || 5 || 8:
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row - 1][column - 2] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column - 2] || completeSudoku[row + 1][column - 1]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
case 2 || 5 || 8:               //If the number is being loaded into row 2, 5 or 8
    switch (column)
    {
    case 0 || 3 || 6:           //Check all other spaces in the same 3x3 grid   
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row - 2][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row - 2][column + 2] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column + 2]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    case 1 || 4 || 7:
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row - 2][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row - 2][column + 1] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column + 1]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    case 2 || 5 || 8:
        if (temporary == (completeSudoku[row - 2][column - 2] || completeSudoku[row - 2][column - 1] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column - 2] || completeSudoku[row - 1][column - 1]))
        {
            indicator = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
return indicator;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
case 0 || 3 || 6:       //If the number is being loaded into row 0,3 or 6
```

to

```
case 0:
case 3:
case 6:       //If the number is being loaded into row 0,3 or 6
```

... and so on, with your other `case` statements.

Your code `case 0 || 3 || 6`

is evaluated as `case (0 || 3 || 6)`

which becomes `case (false || true || true)`

which becomes `case (true)`, which wasn't what you intended.

Comment: Can you please explain to the user a bit more why that is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`case` statements MUST be values. You're trying to compare against the results of EXPRESSIONS.

e.g. given this code:

```
switch($foo) {
   case $bar || $baz: 
       ...
}
```

rewritten as an conventional if() it will be executed exactly the same as:

```
$temp = $bar || $baz;   // boolean OR operation, $temp becomes true/false
if ($foo == $temp) {
    ...
```

You're trying to treat it as:

```
if (($temp == $bar) || ($temp == $baz))
```

which it definitely isn't.

If you want to compare multiple values and have each of them execute the same bit of code, then use the `switch` fall-through behavior:

```
switch($foo) {
    case $bar:
    case $baz:
          .... do something
          break;
```